# default value if a column doesnt exist in the SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below sample code. Assuming I do not know if a particular column exists in a table or not, how could I write the query in a way that I can default the column value to 'Not available' if the column doesn't exist in the table?

**Example**:

```
select COL1, COL2,
CASE
    WHEN OBJECT_ID('COL3') IS NULL THEN 'Not Available'
    ELSE COL3
END AS COL3
from TABLE1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't really do this with regular SQL, and in fact I'm pretty sure your above statement won't even compile unless `COL3` already really exists.

Comment: yes this sql doesnt work, its just to illustrate what i am trying to achieve here.

Comment: You can probably do this from a stored procedure.

Comment: Simply `select * from table1`?

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this since a query that references a non-existent column will not compile. But I think you have larger issues if the schema is unknown at run time.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky to do (without dynamic SQL), but there is a way by playing with the scoping rules in SQL.  You can do this assuming you have a unique or primary key in the table:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2,
       (select col3                               -- no alias!
        from table1 tt1
        where tt1.id = t1.id                      -- the primary/unique key
       ) col3 
from table1 t1 cross join
     (values ('Not Available')) v(col3)           -- same name
```

The subquery will fetch `col3` from the `table1` in the subquery if it exists.  Otherwise it will reach out and find `col3` from the `values()` clause.